# Trouble trying to update display driver for Windows 7 that is running on Macbook

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display, boot-camp, display-settings

I have an issue with display setting on Windows that I installed on 15 inch Macbook via boot camp. The [display is set to Mobile PC Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIvj6.png). I have tried to go to [AMD Site and download the right driver](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonmob_win7-64.aspx), however when I try to install it I get the following message: "AMD Catalyst Mobility cannot be downloaded due to incompatible hardware/software on your computer. Your computer does not contain proper graphics adapter."

[image]

How do I fix this display issue and get right resolution on my monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use Apple's Boot Camp within Windows to provide suitable system drivers.

**[Go here for suitable Windows Boot Camp Drivers](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#boot%20camp).**

Failing that, I'd [explore extracting the installer package from AMD in to the files stored within](http://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20extract%20files%20from%20a%20windows%20installer). Then via Device Manager, tell it to update the associated hardware devices and tell it to look in the location you extracted the installer's payload in to. But REALLY, just use Apple's prepared Boot Camp Drivers.

Also note, Apple puts a copy of their Boot Camp drivers for Windows on the OSX Installation Disks (second one, I think). Though now with Lion, I'm not sure how that works - but their website has the goods, so whatever.

Answer (score 0):

your best solution to the get the drivers to work properly would be the apple boot camp I believe the latest version is bootcamp 3.0 if you have the original Lion disc it has boot camp drivers on that disc all you need to do is pop that it in, it will then autorun and click install. After when you're done that confirm if there's any new patch or updates version for your bootcamp apple is usually good for that go to their apple site and in their search bar put in bootcamp I bet you, you'll see a couple of different version go with what's the newest and read what the fixes is for they usually explain on there.

Hope that helps.